# Should interquartile range (IQR) be reported as one number or as a range?

Tags: definition, interquartile

Is is there a standard how to report interquartile range (IQR)? It seems that different practices are used, some report it as one number and others as a range (25th and 75th percentile/quantile 1 - quantile 2)?

Or is it OK to report IQR as a range?

Comment: A hyphen isn't wrong, but I think it is not essential either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We often (usually?) use IQR rather than SD because the data are ordinal, skewed or otherwise non-N.
By simply giving the median and difference (i.e. 7(10)) instead of 7(6 to 16) we may discard important information.
I would much rather report (and read) median and the actual IQR limits.

Answer (score 7):

[Interquartile range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range) is a *range*, so a difference between third and first quartiles *IQR = Q3 - Q1*. So it *is* a single number statistic, so this is exactly how you report it.

Comment: You can also report the 25th and the 75th percentile (which are the 1st and the 3rd quartile). The reader can then subtract one from the other to obtain the IQR, but a pair of quartiles is not an IQR.

Comment: Indeed. There are no absolute rules here. Giving **the quartiles as well as the interquartile range** (or distance, or spread, other terms used) can be fine. If some reviewer or editor or supervisor objects to the repetition or space used, you may need to choose or comply.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand this answer. Assuming that Q1=10 and Q3=17, does your answer "this is is exactly how you report it" mean that it should be reported as "7" or as "10 to 17". If it is the former then I disagree unless at least one of Q1 and Q3 is supplied, because the width of the interval would float unanchored.

Comment: @MichaelLew IQR is the range by definition. Of course, as noticed in the comments, you can report the quartiles along the range, but IQR statistic itself is their difference, so calling the individual quartiles "IQR" would be incorrect. Moreover, the number is not less anchored than other measures of spread, say standard deviation.

Comment: Thank you guys for clarification. IMO there really is a difference and it may be useful to use percentiles or quartiles with some distributions as they are "anchored", allowing straight-forward interpration.

Comment: @st4co4 yes, showing two numbers instead of one does not take much more space and gives you additional information (and anyone can take the difference to calculate IQR if needed), though this is not called "IQR" but is just reporting the quantiles themselves.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to report the two numbers, that would be reporting *the first and third quartiles*; this is a fine thing to report, but not what is conventionally intended by the term "interquartile range".

The use of the term dates back to [Galton,1881](http://jeff560.tripod.com/i.html) and his use of it then appears consistent with the current convention, which is to refer to the difference of the quartiles (e.g. as in the opening paragraph of the relevant article in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Interquartile_range&oldid=974215141)).